# How to see Scala Documentation in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, documentation

I am trying to learn Scala and I have quite some experience with Java. Usually when I want to know information about a class or function, I look at the source code and its javadoc.

Unfortunately, when I open Scala's `Stream` class file for example, it looks like this:

```
abstract class Stream[+A]() extends scala.collection.AbstractSeq[A] with scala.collection.immutable.LinearSeq[A] with scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate[A, scala.collection.immutable.Stream] with scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized[A, scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A]] with scala.Serializable {
 this : scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A] =>
  override def companion : scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion[scala.collection.immutable.Stream] = { /* compiled code */ }
  def isEmpty : scala.Boolean
  def head : A
  def tail : scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A]
  protected def tailDefined : scala.Boolean
  def append[B >: A](rest : => scala.collection.TraversableOnce[B]) : scala.collection.immutable.Stream[B] = { /* compiled code */ }
  def force : scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A] = { /* compiled code */ }
  def print() : scala.Unit = { /* compiled code */ }
  def print(sep : scala.Predef.String) : scala.Unit = { /* compiled code */ }
  override def length : scala.Int = { /* compiled code */ }
  override def toStream : scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A] = { /* compiled code */ }
  override def hasDefiniteSize : scala.Boolean = { /* compiled code */ }
  //... and much more...
```

Am I using a Scala version without documentation? Is the functionaly deemed so implicit that it does not require explanation? Or am I supposed to always visit their site for documentation? These questions come to mind here. However, the main thing that I am interested in:

What is the most convenient way, using Scala in IntelliJ, to quickly look up documentation for classes and functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Add to a New Project

This is the easiest approach.

> File -> New -> Project... -> [Scala in LHS list] -> [SBT in RHS list] -> [Next button]

You should now be in the "New Project" dialog.  Here you should see a "Download" section with a "Sources" checkbox.  You can tick this to download the full source code including documentation.  Then when you bring up the definition like you did there (using CMD + B) you should see the code as well as any documentation.

[image]

#### Add to an Existing Project

If you want to add to an existing project.  This is more complicated and depends on what version of IDEA you are using.  For IDEA 14 and Scala 2.11.7:

> File -> Project Structure... -> Global Libraries ->  [Scala on the LHS] -> [plus sign]

and add the following for the Sources:

> [path to home]/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/srcs/scala-library-2.11.7-sources.jar

and for the JavaDocs:

> [path to home]/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/docs/scala-library-2.11.7-javadoc.jar

Comment: Adding the javadoc to Global Libraries worked great, thanks!

Comment: You need to add ref to sources only: [path to home]/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/srcs/scala-library-X.X.X-sources.jar